# How to pass a date range to a script?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following piece of code:

```
def parse_args():
    """Takes in arguments from command when run

    :return: date
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(sys.argv)
    parser.add_argument('-d')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    d_param = args.d

    if d_param is None:
        d_param = datetime.today().date() - BDay(1)
    else:
        d_param = datetime.strptime(d_param, "%Y%m%d")

    d_param = d_param.date()

    return d_param
```

So currently it only takes the one date parameter. For e.g:
`script.py -d 20210110`
How can I pass a date range? Like if I want the script to run from lets say 1st of January to 10th of January. So basically 20210101 to 20210110. Is it possible to give an option of either a date range or one date?

P.S- Currently I am using the date in the script to calculate some field.

Comment: Sure, you can add code that allows you to pass it another value and have your argparse split the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a start date an optional end date:

```
def parse_args():
    """Takes in arguments from command when run

    :return: date
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(sys.argv)
    parser.add_argument('-s')
    parser.add_argument('-e')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    start_param = args.s
    end_param = args.e

    if start_param is None:
        start_param = datetime.today().date() - BDay(1)
    else:
        start_param = datetime.strptime(d_param, "%Y%m%d")


    if end_param is None:
        end_param = # PUT YOUR DEFAULT END DATE HERE
    else:
        end_param = datetime.strptime(d_param, "%Y%m%d")

    start_param = d_param.date()
    end_param = d_param.date()

    return start_param, end_param
```

Answer (score 0):

this what I have done finally:

```
    if d_param is None:
        start_date = end_date = (datetime.today().date() - BDay(1)).date()

    else:
        dates = d_param.split('-')

        # User supplied "-d 20170101" argument.
        if len(dates) == 1:
            start_date = end_date = datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%Y%m%d").date()

        # User supplied "-d 20170101-20170131" argument.
        else:
            start_date = datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%Y%m%d").date()
            end_date = datetime.strptime(dates[1], "%Y%m%d").date()

    # Weekdays between start_date and end_date. Does not take holidays
    # into consideration.
    date_range = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date)

    # If length is 0, it means there are no weekdays between start_date
    # and end_date.
    if len(date_range) == 0:
        log.error('No weekdays between start date {} and end date {}'
                  .format(start_date, end_date))
        sys.exit(1)
```